# Remove events on an HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I have a `textarea` element. Somewhere in this mess of legacy code I believe an event is registered preventing me from entering text into the textarea.  I have tried the following code.

```js
$('#clinicalNotesEditable').off("keyup keydown keypress change blur");

$('#clinicalNotesEditable').on("click", function() {
  $(this).attr('disabled', false);
  $(this).attr('readonly', false);
  console.log('Click on textarea by ID');
  // I can see the CLICK event is captured.
});


$('#clinicalNotesEditable').on("keyup keydown keypress", function() {
  console.log('Key pressed on textarea by ID');
  // I do not see this message.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="noteseditable" id="clinicalNotesEditable" style="width: 370px !important; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; -ms-overflow-y: scroll;" placeholder="click here to enter a note" rows="8"></textarea>
```

The only thing I can think of is that I am not properly using `.off()` correctly.  How can I remove all the events from the `clinicalNotesEditable` element?

Comment: You are using `off()` correctly. It's hard to say what the issue is as there's no problem in your snippet.

Comment: `.off()` will only remove event listeners that were added with jQuery, not if they were added with plain JavaScript.

Comment: You can use DevTools to see all the event listeners that are attached to an element.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the event was added with jQuery.  That is mostly what is used in this shop.

Comment: Also, `$("#clinicalNotesEditable").off()` will not turn off handlers delegated from a container.

Comment: @Barmar is there a way to do that?  I think that the disable piece may come from a parent or container....

Comment: You'd need to know which container, since you have to call `.off()` on the same element.

Comment: The code at the question removes the event handlers then reattached event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate `jQuery._data(<DOM element>, 'events')` and remove both delegated and non-delegated events

```js
$("body").on('click', '#clinicalNotesEditable', function() {
  console.log('delegated');
});

$("body").on('click', function() {
  console.log('not delegated');
});

$('#clinicalNotesEditable').on("click", function() {
  $(this).attr('disabled', false);
  $(this).attr('readonly', false);
  console.log('Click on textarea by ID');
});


$('#clinicalNotesEditable').on("keyup keydown keypress", function() {
  console.log('Key pressed on textarea by ID');
  //I see this in the CONSOLE
});

var selector = '#clinicalNotesEditable';

$.each([$(window), $(document), $("*")], function(key, value) {
  $.each(value, function(k, v) {
    var event = $._data(v, "events");
    if (event !== undefined) {
      $.each(event, function(a, b) {
        if (b[0].selector === selector) {
          $(v).off(a, '**');
        } else {
          if ('#' + v.id === selector) {
            $(selector).off(a);
          }
        }
      });    
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="noteseditable" id="clinicalNotesEditable" style="width: 370px !important; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; -ms-overflow-y: scroll;" placeholder="click here to enter a note" rows="8"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the order of the code you have here, if you re-arrange the code as the following:

> ```
> $('#clinicalNotesEditable').on("keyup keydown keypress", function() {
>   console.log('Key pressed on textarea by ID');
>   //keyup keydown and keypress events are removed
> });
> $('#clinicalNotesEditable').off("keyup keydown keypress change blur");
>
> $('#clinicalNotesEditable').on("click", function() {
>   $(this).attr('disabled', false);
>   $(this).attr('readonly', false);
>   console.log('Click on textarea by ID');
> });
> ```

keyup keydown keypress events are removed, and you will see the text "Click on textarea by ID"  in the console. I am not sure if this is what you are trying to achieve. I ran the code and I could add text in textarea.

Comment: There is an event bound to the element somewhere higher up the chain that is keeping me from entering text into the textarea.

Comment: Since you mentioned this is from a mess legacy code, instead of using jQuery .on() method, please try using the pure JavaScript to remove/add event like below:

document.getElementById("clinicalNotesEditable").addEventListener("keydown", function(){
  console.log('Key pressed on textarea by ID');
});

or here is my second thought:

Make sure there is no disabled="disabled" HTML attribute being applied behind the scene by javascript.

Comment: Also make sure there is ONLY one version of jQuery library is being loaded.

Comment: Only the 3.2.1 version is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can unbind() instead of off()

```js
$('#clinicalNotesEditable').off("keyup keydown keypress change blur");

$('#clinicalNotesEditable').on("click", function() {
  $(this).attr('disabled', false);
  $(this).attr('readonly', false);
  console.log('Click on textarea by ID');
});


$('#clinicalNotesEditable').on("keyup keydown keypress", function() {
  console.log('Key pressed on textarea by ID');
  //I see this in the CONSOLE
});
$('#clinicalNotesEditable').unbind()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="noteseditable" id="clinicalNotesEditable" style="width: 370px !important; vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; -ms-overflow-y: scroll;" placeholder="click here to enter a note" rows="8"></textarea>
```